# Is clock-based timing reliable when CPU frequency is variable?

Tags: c, cpu, clock, frequency, elapsed

A common way to measure elapsed time is:

```
const clock_t START = clock();
// ...
const clock_t END = clock();
double T_ELAPSED = (double)(END - START) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

I know this is not the best way to measure real time, but I wonder if it works on a system with a variable frequency CPU. Is it just wrong?

Comment: Presumably, CLOCKS_PER_SEC is defined within a header file as a constant value. If the underlying parameter represented by the value can change and you don't change the constant accordingly then, no, your elapsed time measurement won't be correct.

Comment: If you're doing benchmarking then it's best to set the CPU frequency governor to "performance", at least temporarily, so that you can get accurate measurements, unskewed by clock speed variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are system architectures that change the frequency of the CPU but have a separate and constant frequency to drive a system clock.  One would think that a `clock()` function would return a time independent of the CPU frequency but this would have to be verified on each system the code is intended to run on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to use on a variable clock speed CPU.

http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/KnownHardwareIssues

NTP (network time prototcol) daemon on linux had issues with it.

Most OS's have some API calls for more accurate values, an example being on windows, QueryPerformanceCounter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx